# Very strange localhost connections on linux workstation. Need help identifiying the source

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, udp, netstat

The following is the output of `netstat` on a Ubuntu machine. Can someone help decrypt the output? I am especially curious what the  `::1:43213` connection is.

Also, why are there so many connections from localhost to localhost on both v4 and v6 tcp/udp?????

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7337          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7337                :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 ::1:43213               ::1:43213               ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `netstat -p` as root to show the program PID, then `ps faux | grep ^<PID>`.

A number of the connections you have listed are listening ports, for instance:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7337          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

is something listening on port 7337 for connections on localhost. It is not connected to another machine. Port 68 is a DHCP/BOOTP server.

Comment: Also, `ps -fup <PID>`.  The "-p" will restrict the output to the specified PID.